# How to set string to a random Textview in an array?

Tags: java, android, arrays, textview

I am building an app with database. The database contains the strings for Textview. I have 6 textviews and 3 of them shall be empty. The user inserts text with Edittext and the text shall be compared with another 3 strings and if correct come to the empty textviews.

```
    t1 = findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    t2 = findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    t3 = findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    t4 = findViewById(R.id.textView7);

    t5 = findViewById(R.id.textView8); //empty
    t6 = findViewById(R.id.textView9);
    t7 = findViewById(R.id.textView10); //empty
    t8 = findViewById(R.id.textView11); //empty


    a = t1.getText().toString();
    b = t2.getText().toString();
    c = t3.getText().toString();


    tL1 = new ArrayList<>();
    tL1.add(a);
    tL1.add(b);
    tL1.add(c);


    tL2 = new ArrayList<TextView>();
    if(t5.equals("")){
        tL2.add(t5);
    }
    if(t6.equals("")){
        tL2.add(t6);
    }
    if(t7.equals("")){
        tL2.add(t7);
    }
    if(t8.equals("")){
        tL2.add(t8);
    }
```

I use Arraylist to build an array with empty textviews. Now I am trying to fill the empty textviews with text. How to put text indo Textview without knowing which text is empty? I tried

> tL2.get(0).setText(a);

but it does not work. This comes out

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main. java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Comment: Are you aware that when you do : `t5.equals("")` you compare a `TextView` to a `String` ?

Comment: I forgot it... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error you get tells you that tL2 is empty. I guess you wanted to compare the text inside the textViews with an empty string, so you should modify your code to look like this:

```
if(t5.getText().equals("")){
    tL2.add(t5);
}
```

Also, it is better to check if tL2 has elements inside, before to use the first element, so I'd modify the last piece of code to look like this:

```
if (tL2.size()>0)
    tL2.get(0).setText(a);
```